# how do i access shop url and access token from multiple files?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I followed this tutorial https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react and I now have an app base which I want to develop from, however, how do I access the shop url (example.myshopify.com) and the accessToken that has been generated on server.js file from another file.

Is there a way to make shop url (example.myshopify.com) and the accessToken a global variable or send to a database so I can access them on all files? I am new to all this so not sure what I am doing.

Edit:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = new Koa();
  server.use(session({ secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }, server));
  server.keys = [SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY];

  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
      scopes: ['read_themes', 'write_themes'],
      async afterAuth(ctx) {
        const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
        ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: 'none'
        });
                  console.log(`${shop}`);
        console.log(`${accessToken}`);


        ctx.redirect('/');
      },

    }),

  );


  server.use(verifyRequest());
  server.use(async (ctx) => {
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    ctx.respond = false;
    ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
    return
  });

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });

});
```

Comment: You should save them in database and keep in session when any store is logged in with your App.

as each request will be sent to shopify domain and you need to pass token in the request header.

Comment: While I am testing is there a way to store them locally? Btw I am using node.js, next.js and react to code the app. Could you check my code please and let me know where I can set it up so I can send the accesstoken and shop to storage please